# elasticsearch set network.host to result of 'hostname -i'

Tags: elasticsearch

I am attempting to set up an elasticsearch cluster. The VMs are RedHat 7 and administered by Puppet. Elasticsearch (2.2) is installed via RPMs managed by Puppet. I would like to have a single elasticesearch.yml file that can be used on all nodes. I can not figure out how to set `network.host` to the VM's IP address without hardcoding the IP address.

I would like to do something similar to `node.name: ${hostname}` but for `network.host`. For example I would like to set network.host to `network.host: ${hostname -i}` but elasticsearch does not start with this configuration.

How can I set network.host to the IP of the VM without hardcoding the actual IP address?

Comment: What error message do you get in the elasticsearch log ?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs. The service just will not start

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within [Elastic Configuration](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-configuration.html):

Setting network.host to `${HOSTNAME}` will insert the domain name into your yml variable.

`network.host = ${HOSTNAME}`

Comment: That worked. Looking at the ES documentation, they never provide an example of network.host set to ${HOSTNAME} so I never tried that. Thanks for the help